# What flap design does the A380 use? Is it Fowler flaps, slotted flaps or a combination?

Tags: aircraft-design, flaps, airbus-a380

I have looked at maintenance manuals, the Airbus website, and Wikipedia but still could not find a definite answer as to what trailing edge flaps the Airbus A380 uses.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Airbus calls them **single slotted, tracked high lift flaps** in [this presentation](https://www.fzt.haw-hamburg.de/pers/Scholz/dglr/hh/text_2008_01_30_A380.pdf):

[image: A380 description]

When watching the flap extension in [this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mae4Dp-B5nA) you can see that the flaps extend backwards and downwards at the same time, which would make them single slotted **Fowler flaps**:

[image: A380 flaps extending]

Answer (score 7):

Adding to @Bianfable's answer, I'd like to address the terminology/usage.

---

When referring to flaps on jetliners, *single-slotted* means *single-slotted Fowler.*

The way a slot is created is in one of two ways:

1. Fixed pivot point below the flap line *(first image below)*

   - Slow airplanes
   - Flaperons on jetliners
2. Flaps extend backward and down (Fowler)

   - Main flaps on jetliners (e.g. A380)

Side note: A "compromise" between the two is using a deep pivot which creates large Fowler motion, and to then droop the spoilers to manage the big gap, as used by the A350 (see [related Q&A](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/88343/14897)).

For the first "simple" type:

> [...] the lower cove panel has to be rotated upward with a slave linkage, so the simple flap turns out to be not quite that simple. The simple slotted flap is **not used** on any modern airliner as a main flap concept, but the concept is used for flaperons.<sup>[ref]</sup> [emphasis added]

The blue circle I added below shows that cove panel; it can be seen on the Boeing 777's flaperons *(second image below).*

> [image]
> Source: ref

> [image]
> Arrow showing the aforementioned door, also note the fixed pivot point. Source: Bill Abbott, CC BY-SA 2.0, [via Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Boeing_777-200_center,_aft,_fuselage,_wing_root_fairing,_main_gear_and_doors,_etc._(2719420955)_(3).jpg)

---

Reference:

- Peter, K. C. "[High-Lift systems on commercial subsonic airliners](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/citations/19960052267)." NASA CR-4746, Sept (1996).

Further reading on developing the A380 high-lift system:

- Neittaanmäki, P., et al. "[AERODYNAMIC DESIGN OF AIRBUS HIGH-LIFT WINGS IN A MULTIDISCIPLINARY ENVIRONMENT](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.602.7484)." (2004).