# What trailing edge flap design does the A350 use? Is it similar to the A380?

Tags: aircraft-design, flaps, airbus-a350

Both Airbuses have similar flap deployment based on some YouTube videos I have watched, just wondering if they both have the same flap design being "Single-Slotted Fowler Flaps".

Answer (score 4):

> [image]
> Image shows spoiler droop. Source: *Delta A350 Landing - Detroit Metro* ([YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4FgNax4VgHQ))

Airbus calls the A350 flaps ***Adaptive Dropped Hinge Flap (ADHF).*** It's single-slotted, and Fowler motion is achieved by a deep pivot point, and the resulting gap is managed by spoiler droop, the latter increases the wing camber. (Spoiler droop is also used by the Boeing 787.)

> If Fowler motion is desired, the hinge will be much more below the wing. A compromise is to choose a deeper hinge position and to control the resulting large gap with means like a spoiler actuation [...] On the A350 XWB the spoiler actuation is modified to let the spoilers not only deploy as primary flight control device upwards, but also down to 12° to follow the flap when it’s deployed on its hinge.<sup>[ref]</sup>

> [image]
> Source: ref

The increased wing camber provides additional lift in the linear range (desirable for long fuselages). The drawback is shallower lift slope in the upper non-linear range, but that can be recovered by using bigger flap angles thanks to the spoiler droop, which delays the flow separation (more gradual transition).

> [image]
> Source: ref

---

Reference:

- Strüber, Henning. "The aerodynamic design of the A350 XWB-900 high lift system." 29th international congress of the aeronautical sciences. 2014. ([PDF](https://www.icas.org/ICAS_ARCHIVE/ICAS2014/data/papers/2014_0298_paper.pdf); icas.org)